# Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I am creating a XML document in c#.

Its all coming together now but for some reason i keep getting tis error.

Here is my code:

```
  FileStream Slide2XmlStream = new FileStream(slide2Xml, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        XmlWriter slide2XmlWriter = null;

        try
        {
            XmlWriterSettings contentTypesSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            contentTypesSettings.Indent = true;
            slide2XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(Slide2XmlStream, contentTypesSettings);

            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartDocument(true);
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "sld","http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString( "a","http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "cSld", null);

            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "spTree", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvGrpSpPr", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvpr", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("name", "");
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", "1");
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvGrpSpPr", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvPr", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "p", "grpSpPr", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "a", "xfrm", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteStartElement( "a", "off", null );
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("y", "0");
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("x", "0");
            slide2XmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

The error keeps appearing on the "a" prefix on the start of the method.
Any help will really be appreaciated.

Comment: What do you mean "on the start of the method"? It would really help if you could write a short but *complete* program which demonstrate the problem - *just* with the call that fails, if possible. (We don't know which of your many method calls is failing.)

Comment: My guess translation of wuestion would be: this is all my code from method, I'am getting error `Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace` on the beginning of method, on line `slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString( "a","http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it. I needed to allow the `xmlns` prefix and allow the string value to be null:

```
slide2XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","a",null,"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");
```

Answer (score 1):

In XML, an element may either be in a namespace, or not (which is considered a backward considered mode, sometimes also called "null namespace").  If you want it in a null namespace, which is what you seem to be requesting near the *end* of the method, then you cannot request a namespace prefix.  There is no way to bind a namespace prefix to a "null namespace".

The converse is possible.  There may be no prefix and the element may either be in a  namespace (*default* namespace), or not in a namespace (*null* namespace).  This depends on the presence of the `xmlns` attribute in the serialized XML document.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `XmlSerializer` and you are getting this exception make sure you do not have any `ShouldSerializeXXX` methods in your classes for xml attributes.

For instance, do not do this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Bar")]
    public string Bar{ get; set; }
    
    public bool ShouldSerializeBar(){ return true; }
}
```